# django-password-reset - how to set attributes

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to use django-password-reset (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-password-reset/0.2) to allow users recovering their passwords.

django-password-reset provides a form where the user can enter their username or email address, and tries to find one of those in the database.
In my project, the user has no username field - only the email field.
Thus, I need to make it search users by the 'email' field only, and not by the 'username' field, which does not exist in my system.

The projects documentation says there are attributes to change this behavior:
http://django-password-reset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html.

However, I simply cannot find out how to set these attributes.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `Recover` view like so:

```
class MyRecover(Recover):
    search_fields = ['email']

myrecover = MyRecover.as_view()
```

because there are two recover urls, you need to pass the one with signature first and then the overridden one and then the included one, seems not very DRY, but it's the only way to make the urls be dispatched correctly:

```
url(r'^recover/(?P<signature>.+)/$', 'password_reset_recover.views.recover_done',
    name='password_reset_sent'),
# next we override our url, assuming your app name is called 'core'
url(r'^recover/$', 'core.views.myrecover', name='password_reset_recover'),
url(r'^/', include('password_reset.urls')),
```

Comment: That worked! I was missing the URLs. However, I applied to smaller fixes to the code (see edit). Hope the changes will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `django-password-reset` says that it uses `django.contrib.auth.models.User` (the django built in `User` model) to search for `username` or `email`.  So here a username would exist.

If you want to change the functionality of the `django-password-reset` you can go into the `forms.py` file and change the form's `search_fields` variable (and other logic) so that it only searches by email.

Here is the hyperlink to the forms.py:

https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset/blob/master/password_reset/forms.py

I'd start with changing the `PasswordRecoveryForm`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I would like to avoid direct changes in the django-password-reset code, as I want to deploy the system on another machine without having to make the same changes again there.